# SecurityError with HTTPS iFrame on Firefox

Tags: javascript, java, html, web-applications, onesignal

For my internship project I'm working on, a java webapp, I need to send notifications to a **not fully HTTPS** website. OneSignal offers the possibility to do so.

At first, to test their service, I hardcoded direclty the client SDK javascript inside some `<script>` tags in my jsp file and it worked fine.

```
<script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js" async='async'></script>
<script>
  var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
  OneSignal.push(["init", {
    appId: "my-app-id",
    autoRegister: false, 
    notifyButton: {
        enable: true
    }
  }]);
</script>
```

However, I had to move my javascript into a js file as the development rules of my company specify that javascript should not be in a jsp file. So I linked the code to a button to manually activate it using `document.querySelector('.id-foo').addEventListener('click', initOneSignal)`.

The javascript file is then dynamically loaded at the footer of my jsp.

Here is my js file :

```
(function() {
    document.querySelector('.js-initOneSignal').addEventListener('click', initOneSignal);

    function initOneSignal() {  
        var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
        OneSignal.push(["init", {
            appId: "my-app-id",
            autoRegister: false, 
            notifyButton: {
                enable: true
            }
        }]);
    };
})();
```

However, it's not working anymore (on **Firefox only**, no problem on Chrome) as I get this message from OneSignalSDK.js which tries to open an iFrame to https://my-app-name.onesignal.com/webPushIframe but is not able to and times out.

> SecurityError : The operation is insecure

Apparently this is a bug https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/95. The issue is marked as closed while I think it should be open again, newer version of Firefox might have changed something. Here is the link to the my github issue : https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Website-SDK/issues/359

Did someone encountered the issue and found a workaround?

Thanks in advance for any help !

PS : I'm using Firefox 60

PPS : The iFrame OneSignal tries to open :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDK.js"></script>
        <script>OneSignal._initHttp({
            appId: "myappid",
            subdomainName: "mysubdomainname",
            origin: "http://my-website"
        });</script>
        <link rel="manifest" href="manifest_json">
     </head>
     <body>
     </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :**

Still no response from OneSignal. Their "Support" link is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution ! and it was kind of obvious. I just needed to **reset Firefox** and it's working fine now. Thanks to this [page](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/231982/sites-does-not-load-on-newest-firefox/) which gave my the hint.

This issue was related to the fact I'm switching between HTTP and HTTPS configurations in order to test differents webpsuh solutions/service. To do so, I have to use a custom SSL certificate to fake being on a fully HTTPS website and add a security expection in Firefox. When coming back to HTTP, my Firefox configuration was sill affected by this exception somehow and therefore Firefox was throwing a Security Error.